# Find what percentile a number ranks within a given range?

Tags: r, dplyr

suppose I have a number distribution like this.

```
set.seed( 145)
data <- runif(100, 0, 500)
q = quantile( data, probs=c ( seq(0,1, by=.01) ) )
```

for a given number, 300, I would like to know what percentile it ranks in data?
I can I guess figure out which q bin it is between but this is convoluted, is there an easier way?

thanks.

Comment: the `punif` function goes from observation to percentile so `punif(300, 0, 500)` return .6 which is the 60% percentile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `findInterval`

```
names(q)[findInterval(300, q) +1]
[1] "54%"
```

where `q` corresponds to

```
> q[55]
     54% 
306.9737
```

Comment: thank you, this works, also per above this works as well `punif(300, min ( data), max ( data) ) `